# copy the value inside a list which is fetched from database to a text box and make it editable

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I have a list of items which is fetched and displayed from database. It will appear as a navigation bar. When I click on any of the list item I want to copy the name of item to a textbox and make it editable, there should be an option to delete and save the editable name of list item.

```
 <div id="nav">
            <input type="button" value="Add new" onclick="location.href = 'addindustry.php';">
            <?php
            $conn=get_dbconnect();
            $sql="select * from industry";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
             echo "<ul>";
             echo "<li>";
             echo "<a href='modifyindustry.php'>";
             echo $row['name'];
             echo "</a>";
             echo "</li>";
             echo "</ul>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

this $row['name'] will fetch 18 industy name from database

Comment: Okay, good luck with that.

Comment: i haven got exactly what u r after, but i think what u want to do is make a link with the name u want to edit, then when u click on it, it takes u to a page that u use "$_GET" to fetch the data from the url and display it in an input so u can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

you need a page to show your industries:

industries.php

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='modifyindustry.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And a page to edit your data:

modifyindustry.php

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'select * from industries where' .
    ' id=' . $_GET['id']); ?>
<form action="modifyindustry.php?id=<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" method="...">
<?php if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='<?php echo $row['name']; ?>' />";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
<?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

- Note that $_GET['id'] has a dangerous vulnerability. That was just an example. You need to use prepared statements for your queries.